# Select then update - sql question

Tags: sql

How do I make this query first find all professors whose picture IS NULL and THEN update with a new value for column 'picpath'

I have:

```
SELECT * FROM Professor
WHERE picpath IS NULL;
```

Is it possible to form this all in a subquery perhaps? Can someone help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about, you could do

```
update professor set picpath=<newvaluehere> where picpath is null
```

Answer (score 0):

Using SQL Server's `OUTPUT` clause (MSSQL208 and above) you can kinds of do the same but the other way around i.e. `UPDATE` then `SELECT` the affected rows e.g.

```
UPDATE professor 
   SET picpath = 'C:\'
OUTPUT inserted.*
 WHERE picpath IS NULL;
```